# resize devtmpfs on /etc/fstab

Tags: debian, udev, tmpfs

I try resize my `devtmpfs` size, by add a row to `/etc/fstab`.

This is my fstab file :

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/mmcblk0p2 during installation
UUID=6e7b65b0-f9ce-4a0d-97fd-73374d0a8492 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/mmcblk0p1 during installation
UUID=26c4e594-31fe-49ab-844a-a2e7e195ea36 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
0       0
# Define devtmpfs size
udev /dev   devtmpfs  rw,relatime,size=102400k,nr_inodes=217992,mode=755  1  0
```

But during reboot machine I get these rows :

```
EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p1): mounting ext2 file system using the ext4 subsystem
EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p1): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
[....] Mounting local filesystems...mount: udev is already mounted or /dev busy
failed.
```

What I make wrong ?

Comment: It's possible that `/dev` is mounted by the initial ramdisk (i.e, before your root filesystem is mounted, which means before your fstab is available).  It may be possible to modify the `fstab` on the initial ramdisk, but it might help us if you could explain why you need to resize your `/dev` filesystem.

Comment: I want shrink size of devtmpfs for performaance improve. How to modify initial ramdisk you mention above ?

Comment: I doubt shrinking `/dev` would increase performance.

Comment: What influence should be after I shrink it ? I didn't check how much my system use during load process , but on regular run show it never used it, so why I should declare it about 800MB and not 20 MB

Comment: That duplicate doesn’t answer the question though. (Whether it’s worth answering is another question!)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use *initramfs-tools* to generate your initramfs as this is the default.  Devtmpfs is mounted by its `init` script, which you find at `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/init`. The jessie version contains:

```
tmpfs_size="10M"
if [ -e /etc/udev/udev.conf ]; then
        . /etc/udev/udev.conf
fi
if ! mount -t devtmpfs -o size=$tmpfs_size,mode=0755 udev /dev; then
[...]
```

This means that

- the default is 10 MB under jessie, so you probably run stretch, uses half of your physical memory;
- under jessie you could prescribe a different size by setting `tmpfs_size` in `/etc/udev/udev.conf`.

Under stretch, you can't tune this, but as (dev)tmpfs size is a maximum size only, it wouldn't save you any memory anyway. You can remount your `/dev` to set a different maximum size, though:

```
# mount -oremount,size=10M /dev
```